# Handling CORS in Nginx as a reverse proxy

Tags: go, nginx, cors, nginx-reverse-proxy

We encountered a very weird behavior when using Nginx as a reverse proxy.

We have REST services that need to be used with the browser, We configured these HTTP `Golang` services to handle `CORS` using [cors](https://github.com/rs/cors) package.

We noticed that when the browser triggers a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) the request doesn't go to the backend service and instead Nginx responds with the status `405 Method Not Allowed` and the request is never forwarded or proxied to the backend service at all.

To fix this issue we had to handle `OPTIONS` requests manually from the `location` directive, This is very limited as we need the liberty to update for example the allowed headers using `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` based on the requested route.

How can we forward any `Preflight` or `OPTIONS` request to the backend to handle?

> NOTE: We are using default Nginx configurations according to the official [Nginx docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx).

file: `main.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/rs/cors"
)

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("Hello World"))
    })

    r := cors.AllowAll().Handler(mux)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", r)
}
```

file: `server.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        
        # Handling OPTIONS for this location directive.
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
          add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "$http_origin";
          add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials 'true';
          add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'Authorization, Content-Type, Origin, X-Requested-With, Accept';
          add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
          add_header Content-Type 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
          return 204;
        }

        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        proxy_set_header X-Original-Remote-Addr $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Original-Host $host;
    }
}
```

Related:

- [Handling OPTIONS request in nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227939/handling-options-request-in-nginx)
- [Cross Origin preflight request in Nginx Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64889645/13798172)

Comment: Please don't link to a Gist. Instead, make your question self-contained by adding a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You should configure CORS in at most one place. If you do it in NGINX, don't use rs/cors and vice versa.

Comment: @jub0bs I've updated the post with the demo built-in.
I want to handle CORS using my backend service, not Nginx to have more flexibility, But I can't do so, because NGINX is not allowing any OPTIONS preflight requests to my backend in the first place.

Comment: You write: _NGINX is not allowing any OPTIONS preflight requests to my backend in the first place._ You need to fix this first. Find out why NGINX is blocking `OPTIONS` requests, and you'll be one step closer to solving your issue.