CORS issue with NGinx and fetch react native
I'm facing a cors issue only with web browser when I want to implement a react native app.
Alhough I've configured
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

I'm still getting a CORS error from the browser.
Is there anything that I'm missing?
client:
return fetch(newURL, {
    method: "GET",
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
})

server nginx:
       location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            add_header 'allow' 'GET';
            add_header 'access-control-allow-origin' '*';
            add_header 'access-control-allow-credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'access-control-expose-headers' 'filename';

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000/;
    }

}
interaction



The query is failing because of preflights with CORS.
Here is the msg
Access to fetch at 'xxxx/access/verif?email=xxxx&v=0.1&1733744786626' from origin 'localhost:19006' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Any clue?
Thanks!

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

And please quote the actual error message. So far we only know that you get a CORS error, but not even which one in particular.

This question is similar to: Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I's edited with the difference highlighted, the difference is although the header returns Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
I'm getting a CORS error. Do I need to create a new post to not be voted negatively? ;)

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource is a CORS error message. What CORS error message do you get?

I' getting Access to fetch at 'https://xxxx/access/verif?email=xxxx&v=0.1&1733744786626' from origin 'http://localhost:19006' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
However, using curl, I can see the header is there.
It might be not present with the preflight though

Looks like I found part the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64889343/cross-origin-preflight-request-in-nginx-proxy but because I'm using authentication it's not working completly.

I actually found the answer. I'll post it once it is portable.

The problem was that because I'm using spring boot, OPTIONS http method was not handled properly. Additionally because I provide a Bearer, CORS restrictions don't support wildcard.
Here is my Nginx working configuration, you might need to add some http methods according to your needs.
 location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
               add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin ;
               add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials 'true' ;
               add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
               add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'content-type,authorization';
               add_header Content-Type text/plain;
               add_header Content-Length 0;
               return 204;
            }
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials 'true' ;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'content-type,authorization';


            proxy_hide_header "X-Frame-Options";

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000/;
    }


$request_method = OPTIONS is too strict: not all OPTIONS requests are CORS-preflight requests. You're going to trap all OPTIONS requests in the logic of your CORS middleware.

@jub0bs what do you suggest?

=> https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#4-categorise-requests-correctly

ideally it should be handled by spring, I agree, but there is no much point as it is a react native app. Also, ios and android apps are not causing issue with CORS, it is only when we test though the web.
